# Who comes first, father or teacher?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring, kavod, chinuch-education

The Rambam writes [based on Pirkei Avot 4:12, Keritot 28a and other places]:

> Just as a person is commanded to honor and revere his father, so is he under an obligation to honor and revere his teacher, even to a greater extent than his father... There is no honor higher than that which is due to the teacher. [Mishneh Torah, Torah Study 5:1]

I understand the stated rationale (parents give you life in this world, teachers give you life in the World to Come), but still, how can that be?  I know we don't rank commandments, but honoring parents is one of the Ten Commandments and honoring teachers is not.

You may say: He only said the *father* comes after the teacher.  The *mother* comes *before* the teacher:

> If he and his father and his teacher are captives, he himself comes before his teacher; and his teacher before his father; but his mother comes before all. [Shulchan Arukh, Yoreh De'ah 252:9]

But then we are also taught that father and mother and equal on the scale of honor and reverence:

> You might think... the honor due to the father exceeds the honor due to the mother [because Exodus 20:12 says "Honor your father and your mother" with the father listed first] , [but] the Torah stated [later], "Every man shall revere his mother and his father." [Leviticus 19:3]", to teach that both are equal. [Keritot 28a; Genesis R. 1:15]

So what's the teaching here?  Do we have a dispute?  Are the rabbis engaging in hyperbole?

Comment: Mother being redeemed first has nothing to do with her being a parent, it has to do with her being a woman. See Yorah Deah 252:8 (the one right before your quote).